# Is it permitted to sit with your sister in law in same room?

Tags: halal-haram, hijab, men-women, non-mahram, modesty

When my family visit my wife's family we stay in their house as guests. Her sisters will come into the bedroom we stay in to chat to her and I'm usually present and may chat to me wearing the headscarf and loose dress but no abaya.

Islamically I'm a non mahram to them even though I'm closely related (their sister's husband) so is it permitted for us to sit in the same room and chat (but never alone such as just 1 sister and me) if they wear the headscarf and loose dress?
The other problem is that I really like one of the sisters so it can be a test to just chat without observing her beauty.

Interestingly they cover their faces when they go out in public but for close male non-mahram relatives will show the face in the house wearing a headscarf.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are not alone with them then it is permitted for you to sit with your sisters in law if they are wearing a headscarf and dressed modestly.

But you should guard against sin and lower your gaze, especially if you are attracted to one of them. Modesty falls equally on men and women and you must observe hijab.

If you are unable to resist temptation then it is best that you remove yourself from the situation.